# Is there a reason to throw an exception twice?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw

Debugging production code I came across something I had not seen before and am not aware of a valid purpose.  In several methods of one of our controllers we have try-catch blocks.  The interesting part is there are 2 throw statements in one of the catches.

Is there any reason to have 2 throw statements?  If so, in what circumstance(s) does that make sense?

```
        try
        {
           //statements
        }
        catch (SoapException se)
        {
            //Log statement
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log statement
            throw;
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: I am just curious, are the `throw` statements really consecutive like shown in the post or just logically consecutive in the real code?

Comment: They are actually consecutive, which is why it was so strange when I saw it.  I was thinking, like the answers here, that the second throw would never be reached (and even if it was reached, what would be the point?) so it was perplexing.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check (i.e. answers) everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there is no reason to `throw` twice. The second `throw` will never be reached.

It is also similar to having

```
public int GetNumber()
{
    return 1;
    return 2; // Never reached
}
```

**Update**

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a great tool to check things like this.

In this case it will grey out the second `throw` and tell you it is unreachable.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no purpose in throwing an exception twice in a row. The second `throw` can never be reached, and it is most likely a typo, or code that was edited, but never completed and since forgotten about.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you showed, there would be no purpose to the two throw statements. As soon as the first one is hit it starts to work its way back up the call stack until it is caught. The only way for two to make any differance is if the first one was conditional or caught before he second one was hit.

```
    try
    {
       //statements
    }
    catch (SoapException se)
    {
        //Log statement
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log statement
        if (condition)
            throw;
        throw;
    }
```

or

```
    try
    {
       //statements
    }
    catch (SoapException se)
    {
        //Log statement
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log statement
        try
        {
             throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             //Handle first thrown exception.
        }
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: That last code segment is a beauty. Are you sure you didn't pull that out of the source code from `insert my company name here`?

Comment: Is the first `throw` in that last code segment legitimate? The pattern is odd, but there could be a use for that pattern if there were some specific `catch` statements in the last `try`; the idea would be that if an exception isn't caught before the first `catch (Exception ex)`, some sort of exception is going to bubble up, but the last `throw` will only be reached if none of the exception handlers in the last `try` throw their own exception first. I wish C# and vb.net had a nice syntax for code that needs to act upon an exception but knows it will never resolve it.